# rc.local shell script to run socket program

Tags: raspbian, raspberry-pi-os

I have a raspberry pi 4 and i connected a sixfab LTE HAT to it. I wrote a program that works manually (sudo python3 server2.py). I wrote a simple shell script and put it to rc.local that has the following lines in it

```
cd /home/pi/Desktop
sudo python3 server2.py
```

When i check the rc-local.service, i get the message that when i try to send something with the LTE there is a timeout error "connection timed out"

```
sserver.connect((TCP_IP_SERVER,TCP_PORT_SERVER))
```

Note that i have to use sudo because i configured the raspberry to socket connection with wwan0 instead of the wifi using:

```
sserver.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET,25, str("wwan0"+'\0').encode('utf-8'))
```

As i mentioned previously, the program runs manually. Can i ask if you have any comments or ideas on the subject?

Comment: Change the /etc/rc.local lines to `python3 /home/pi/Desktop/server2.py &` that & is super important to fork the process into the background. Also you don't need `sudo` as rc.local runs as root. Also it does NOT run with the same environment as your regular pi shell (watch out for file names without full paths).

Answer (score 5):

One comment or idea to the subject is: **don't use `/etc/rc.local` anymore**!

Debian/Raspbian/Raspberry Pi OS uses **systemd** instead of deprecated **SysV** since years as init system to start and manage services. **rc.local** is a leftover from SysV and only emulated by systemd, but with serious limitations. Have a look at [Compatibility with SysV](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/Incompatibilities/).

You should use a systemd Unit file to start your service. You can find many examples here on this site.

Answer (score 2):

As @Ingo has said in his answer, `systemd` is indeed a valid and current method for starting a program at boot time. I also agree that `/etc/rc.local` should be avoided - this is not so much a matter of opinion as documented fact (see, [for example](https://www.masterkenneth.com/2019/04/replacing-rc-local-in-systemd-linux-systems/)):

> The man page for `systemd-rc-local-generator` states, “*Support for /etc/rc.local is provided for compatibility with specific System V systems only. However, it is strongly recommended to avoid making use of this script today, and instead provide proper unit files with appropriate dependencies for any scripts to run during the boot process.*”

However, there is a valid and current method for doing what you want that you may find simpler, easier and equally effective as long as you follow a few simple rules. This method is called `cron`, and here's how it can work in your case:

#### 1. Open a `crontab` file:

From the command line, enter `crontab -e`, **OR** if you need your script to run with `root` privileges, enter `sudo crontab -e`. If you don't need elevated privileges, you should use the former.

In either case, after entering this command, your terminal will open the `crontab` file in an editor (`nano` is a good choice if prompted to select an editor).

#### 2. Edit the `crontab` file:

In your case, enter the following line at the bottom of the `crontab` file:

```
@reboot ( /bin/sleep 10; /usr/bin/python3 /home/pi/Desktop/server2.py ) >> /home/piDesktop/cronjoblog.txt 2>&1
```

Let's break this down:

- `@reboot` instructs `cron` to run the following commands at boot time
- `sleep 10` tells `cron` to sleep/wait for 10 seconds before proceeding to the next command
- `/usr/bin/python3 /home/pi/Desktop/server2.py` says use `python3` to run the script in `server2.py`
- `>> /home/piDesktop/cronjoblog.txt 2>&1` **redirects** `>>` the `stdout` and `stderr` streams `2>&1` to a text file on your desktop

#### 3. Save the `crontab` file, exit the editor and `reboot` to test:

If you're using `nano` as your editor, <kbd>control</kbd><kbd>o</kbd> to save, acknowledge the proposed filename with <kbd>return</kbd>, and <kbd>control</kbd><kbd>x</kbd> to exit `nano` and return to the command line. Let us know if you run into any issues.

#### Addendum: The simple rules for using `cron` are based on two facts:

1. `cron` **does not inherit your environment variables**

   Consequently, preface commands with an absolute `path`. A related symptom is that any output from a program that runs successfully from the command line is "lost". Lost error messages in particular are not helpful! Therefore: **redirect** all messages to a log file.
2. `cron` **does not know what resources are required to run your program**

   Network and file services may not be available when `cron` is started. If not, `cron` doesn't know what to do! Prefacing commands with `sleep` allows the system to get these services started before `cron` calls on them.